# How do I loop through a serialized list while not modifying the contents except increment the day by 1 from 2017/06/01 to 2017/07/01

Tags: c#, loops, serialization

I'm trying to loop through a list and copy it several times without modifying it except the date. I need to increment the date by 1 from 2017/06/01 - 2017/07/01 but every time I try to the date jumps to the month I indicated except for each day leading to that month and the last item that is added is repeated over and over again instead of repeating the entire list. Below is my code as well as the output that I keep getting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FlightFactory;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Flights
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    StreamWriter sw;
    XmlSerializer serial;
    List<FlightFactories> flightList;
    const string FLIGHT_FILENAME = @"..\..\flights.xml"; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCreateFlights_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        flightList = new List<FlightFactories>();
        FlightFactories f = new FlightFactories("102", 20170601, "0616", "MIA", "SEA", 1550, "10");
        flightList.Add(f);
        //lblResults.Text = P.ToString();

            f = new FlightFactories("103", 20170601, "1016", "MIA", "SEA", 2120, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("145", 20170601, "1316", "MIA", "SEA", 2850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("146", 20170601, "2016", "MIA", "SEA", 1300, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("153", 20170601, "0816", "MIA", "DEN", 1800, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("156", 20170601, "1416", "MIA", "DEN", 2970, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("160", 20170601, "1916", "MIA", "DEN", 1950, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("164", 20170601, "2216", "MIA", "DEN", 850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("167", 20170601, "1016", "MIA", "LAX", 2120, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("172", 20170601, "1216", "MIA", "LAX", 2510, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("174", 20170601, "1716", "MIA", "LAX", 2200, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("176", 20170601, "2316", "MIA", "LAX", 750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("177", 20170601, "0816", "SEA", "DEN", 1800, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("179", 20170601, "1216", "SEA", "DEN", 2510, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("185", 20170601, "1516", "SEA", "DEN", 2750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("186", 20170601, "2016", "SEA", "DEN", 1300, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("188", 20170601, "0616", "LAX", "DEN", 1550, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("200", 20170601, "1016", "LAX", "DEN", 2120, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("202", 20170601, "1416", "LAX", "DEN", 2970, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("204", 20170601, "1916", "LAX", "DEN", 1950, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("206", 20170601, "1316", "SEA", "MIA", 2850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("212", 20170601, "1516", "SEA", "MIA", 2750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("214", 20170601, "1916", "SEA", "MIA", 1950, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("216", 20170601, "2316", "SEA", "MIA", 750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("218", 20170601, "0816", "SEA", "LAX", 1800, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("222", 20170601, "1316", "SEA", "LAX", 2850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("226", 20170601, "1716", "SEA", "LAX", 2200, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("228", 20170601, "2216", "SEA", "LAX", 850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("230", 20170601, "0616", "DEN", "MIA", 1550, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("232", 20170601, "1216", "DEN", "MIA", 2510, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("234", 20170601, "1916", "DEN", "MIA", 1950, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("236", 20170601, "2316", "DEN", "MIA", 750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("238", 20170601, "1416", "LAX", "SEA", 2970, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("241", 20170601, "1716", "LAX", "SEA", 2200, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("243", 20170601, "2016", "LAX", "SEA", 1300, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("247", 20170601, "2316", "LAX", "SEA", 750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("250", 20170601, "0616", "DEN", "LAX", 1550, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("255", 20170601, "1216", "DEN", "LAX", 2510, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("257", 20170601, "1516", "DEN", "LAX", 2750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("259", 20170601, "2016", "DEN", "LAX", 1300, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("260", 20170601, "0816", "DEN", "SEA", 1800, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("262", 20170601, "1316", "DEN", "SEA", 2850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("264", 20170601, "2016", "DEN", "SEA", 1300, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("268", 20170601, "2216", "DEN", "SEA", 850, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("270", 20170601, "1016", "LAX", "MIA", 2120, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("272", 20170601, "1416", "LAX", "MIA", 2970, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("274", 20170601, "1916", "LAX", "MIA", 1950, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);
            f = new FlightFactories("276", 20170601, "2316", "LAX", "MIA", 750, "10");
            flightList.Add(f);

        for (int i = 20170701; i > f.Date; f.Date++)
            {
                flightList.Add(f);
            }           

        serial = new XmlSerializer(flightList.GetType());
        sw = new StreamWriter(FLIGHT_FILENAME);
        serial.Serialize(sw, flightList);
        sw.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flightList = new List<FlightFactories>();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FLIGHT_FILENAME);
        serial = new XmlSerializer(flightList.GetType());
        flightList = (List<FlightFactories>)serial.Deserialize(sr);
        sr.Close();

        foreach (FlightFactories f in flightList)
        {
            lstFlights.Items.Add(f.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

By the way this is in C# in Visual Studio 2013.

[image: Results]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the FlightFacroty code that is being referenced in the Flights namespace sorry for not posting it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FlightFactory
{
    public class FlightFactories
    {
         public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

         public string OrigAirport { get; set; }

         public string DesAirport { get; set; }

         public int Fare { get; set; } 

         public string Seats { get; set; }

         public string StartDate = "06/01/2017"; //Date format is MMDDYYYY

         public string EndDate = "07/01/2017";

         public string Time { get; set; } //Time is HH:mm 24 hour time 

         public FlightFactories() { }


        public FlightFactories ( string FlightNumber, int Date, string Time, string OrigAirport, string DesAirport, int Fare, string Seats)
    {
        this.FlightNumber = FlightNumber;
        this.OrigAirport = OrigAirport;
        this.DesAirport = DesAirport;
        this.Fare = Fare;
        this.Seats = Seats;
        this.Date = Date;
        this.Time = Time;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string flightDate = Date.ToString().Substring(4, 2) + "/" + Date.ToString().Substring(6, 2) + "/" + Date.ToString().Substring(0, 4);
        string flightTime = Time.Substring(0, 2) + ":" + Time.Substring (2, 2);
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate);
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
        string farePrice = Fare.ToString("c");
        return String.Format("{0}, {1} at {2}, {3} to {4}, Cost: {5}, Seat: {6}", FlightNumber, flightDate, flightTime, OrigAirport, DesAirport, farePrice, Seats);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "every time I try to the date jumps to the month I indicated" but you didn't indicated any month. Can you please review your question description?

Comment: the indicated month is 07 or the month of july. So it jumps from 06/01/2017 to 07/01/2017 as shown in the picture.

Comment: @user2792215 - You need to provide a [mcve]. This can't be tested properly unless we can run your code ourselves.

Comment: Why is `Date` an `int` and not a `DateTime`?

Comment: I honestly didn't know about that. This is my first C# program and I'm still learning. Do you think changing it would help?

Comment: I added a StartDate and an EndDate which might make it easier to loop through and also converted it to a DateTime like @pinkfloydx33 suggested. Now I don't know how to add it t the string format correctly to that I can iterate through the dates

Comment: Yes, using DateTime instead of int will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
private void btnCreateFlights_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flightList = new List<FlightFactories>()
    {
        new FlightFactories("102", 20170601, "0616", "MIA", "SEA", 1550, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("103", 20170601, "1016", "MIA", "SEA", 2120, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("145", 20170601, "1316", "MIA", "SEA", 2850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("146", 20170601, "2016", "MIA", "SEA", 1300, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("153", 20170601, "0816", "MIA", "DEN", 1800, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("156", 20170601, "1416", "MIA", "DEN", 2970, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("160", 20170601, "1916", "MIA", "DEN", 1950, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("164", 20170601, "2216", "MIA", "DEN", 850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("167", 20170601, "1016", "MIA", "LAX", 2120, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("172", 20170601, "1216", "MIA", "LAX", 2510, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("174", 20170601, "1716", "MIA", "LAX", 2200, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("176", 20170601, "2316", "MIA", "LAX", 750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("177", 20170601, "0816", "SEA", "DEN", 1800, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("179", 20170601, "1216", "SEA", "DEN", 2510, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("185", 20170601, "1516", "SEA", "DEN", 2750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("186", 20170601, "2016", "SEA", "DEN", 1300, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("188", 20170601, "0616", "LAX", "DEN", 1550, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("200", 20170601, "1016", "LAX", "DEN", 2120, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("202", 20170601, "1416", "LAX", "DEN", 2970, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("204", 20170601, "1916", "LAX", "DEN", 1950, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("206", 20170601, "1316", "SEA", "MIA", 2850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("212", 20170601, "1516", "SEA", "MIA", 2750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("214", 20170601, "1916", "SEA", "MIA", 1950, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("216", 20170601, "2316", "SEA", "MIA", 750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("218", 20170601, "0816", "SEA", "LAX", 1800, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("222", 20170601, "1316", "SEA", "LAX", 2850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("226", 20170601, "1716", "SEA", "LAX", 2200, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("228", 20170601, "2216", "SEA", "LAX", 850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("230", 20170601, "0616", "DEN", "MIA", 1550, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("232", 20170601, "1216", "DEN", "MIA", 2510, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("234", 20170601, "1916", "DEN", "MIA", 1950, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("236", 20170601, "2316", "DEN", "MIA", 750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("238", 20170601, "1416", "LAX", "SEA", 2970, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("241", 20170601, "1716", "LAX", "SEA", 2200, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("243", 20170601, "2016", "LAX", "SEA", 1300, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("247", 20170601, "2316", "LAX", "SEA", 750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("250", 20170601, "0616", "DEN", "LAX", 1550, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("255", 20170601, "1216", "DEN", "LAX", 2510, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("257", 20170601, "1516", "DEN", "LAX", 2750, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("259", 20170601, "2016", "DEN", "LAX", 1300, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("260", 20170601, "0816", "DEN", "SEA", 1800, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("262", 20170601, "1316", "DEN", "SEA", 2850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("264", 20170601, "2016", "DEN", "SEA", 1300, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("268", 20170601, "2216", "DEN", "SEA", 850, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("270", 20170601, "1016", "LAX", "MIA", 2120, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("272", 20170601, "1416", "LAX", "MIA", 2970, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("274", 20170601, "1916", "LAX", "MIA", 1950, "10"),
        new FlightFactories("276", 20170601, "2316", "LAX", "MIA", 750, "10"),
    };

    flightList =
        flightList
            .Select(f => new FlightFactories(/* increment date here */))
            .ToList();

    serial = new XmlSerializer(flightList.GetType());
    sw = new StreamWriter(FLIGHT_FILENAME);
    serial.Serialize(sw, flightList);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Without the full code it is hard to say how to fill out `new FlightFactories(/* increment date here */)`, but you should get the idea.